# The html page displays question marks instead of Russian letters

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

please help if anyone knows what the matter is. I have already tried everything I found on the Internet, but so far to no avail. For some reason, when launching a project in Idea, question marks are displayed on the page instead of Russian letters

What I've already tried:

1. I made sure that the windows console responds to the chcp request with 866
   I read that it is better to set this value
2. Also in the regional standard settings, in the tab additionally, I clicked the **"change
   system language"** button and there unchecked the **"Beta version: Use Unicode (UTF-8) to
   support the language worldwide."** Save and reboot.
3. In files **idea.exe.vmoptions** and **idea64.exe.vmoptions** Added the following line: -
   **Dfile.encoding = UTF-8**
   Also added it in the editor **Idea> EditConfigurations> Tomcat> VM options**. Also added it in
   the editor **Idea> Help> Edit Custom VM Options**
4. Also in the **File> Settings> FileEncodings** settings set **Global Encoding** to UTF-8
   **Project Encoding** to UTF-8 **Default encoding for project files**: UTF-8 Create UTF-8 files
   with NO BOOM
5. In the lower right corner of the editor, I also set UTF-8
6. I put the meta tag in the header in this format. `<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>`
7. I also resave my index.html just in case using a notepad with UTF-8 encoding
8. I launched the index.html page itself by double clicking in the folder and it normally
   displays the button with the Russian language, as well as the test text with the Russian
   language. however, when I click the run Tomcat button in idea for some reason, the page shows
   question marks instead of Russian letters
9. Configured tomcat as said here: https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-utf-8

   And yet, for some reason, when launching the project through idea, Content-type is shown in
   responce-headers: text / html; charset = ISO-8859-1

IntellIJ Idea v2020.1
MavenVersion v3.6.1
Project SDK 1.8 Java version
TomCat v9.0.48

Dependencies
spring-core         5.2.16.RELEASE
spring-context      5.2.16.RELEASE
spring-web          5.2.16.RELEASE
spring-webmvc       5.2.16.RELEASE
thymeleaf-spring5   3.0.12.RELEASE
javax.servlet-api   4.0.1

I found a moment in which the Russian language on the site page turns from letters to question marks.

At first everything opens normally when mine
index is in the directory
webapp> Index
Then when I create two settings classes
SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
and
SpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
and put my index under the path webapp> WEB-INF> index.html
starts to be called through MainController.
From this moment on, Russian letters are no longer recognized.

Here is the minimum code from which the error begins to appear.

**MainController**

```
package ru.shop.three_d_print.сontrollers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class MainController
{
    @GetMapping
    public String index()
    {
        System.out.println("called");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**SpringConfig**

```
package ru.shop.three_d_print.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ru.shop.three_d_print")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry)
    {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine()
    {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver()
    {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return templateResolver;
    }
}
```

**SpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer**

```
package ru.shop.three_d_print.config;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;
public class SpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses()
    {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses()
    {
        return new Class[] {SpringConfig.class};
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings()
    {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

**Index**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    Sentence in english.
    Предложение на русском.
    build 3 inner
</body>
</html>
```

And result:

Sentence in english. ?????µ???»???¶?µ?????µ ???° ??????????????. build 3 inner

Comment: Please specify IntelliJ IDEA, Tomcat and JDK versions you are using and share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CrazyCoder
Thanks for the great idea. In an attempt to create a minimal example, I created a clean project and created index.html and everything works there. Now I just have to copy everything step by step into a new project until I run into the same error. Then it will be clear at what step the problem arose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure all you have to do is to put this in your head!

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Hope it works!

EDIT: I see you are already doing this. Do you have the newest version of HTML? If not, try updating itv

Comment: He already did this. (6)

Comment: What do you mean by version of HTML? This is clearly an encoding problem. Do not use answer to ask questions. See [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering)

Comment: Hm? What do you mean?

Comment: Use comments to get additional informations, not answers. And be sure to know what the problem is before posting an answer. HTML is integrated in browsers and requires no "updates"